# How to add a text above a previous added image and center it above this image with pdfbox?

Tags: java, pdfbox

My aim is to add a image to a pdf and write a text above this image. I have centered the image and the text should be center above the image with a little margin to the image.

Currently the image will be added and centered but the text is not centered.

[image]

Here my current code. The interesting part is where the method drawTitleAtTop will be called. Here i have added the height of the newly added image to the y postion plus a margin of 3. The x coordinate I calculate depending on the incoming text but there is some miscalculation. Any advice?

```
private static void addScaledImage(ImageData imgData, PDDocument pdDocument, Dimension thePdfDimension) {
    ImageHelper helper = Scalr::resize;
    byte[] scaledImage = ImageUtils.resizeImageKeepAspectRatio(helper, imgData.getImageBinary(), thePdfDimension.width);

    PDRectangle rectangle = pdDocument.getPage(0).getMediaBox();
    PDPage page = new PDPage(rectangle);
    pdDocument.addPage(page);
    PDImageXObject pdImage = null;
    try {
        pdImage = PDImageXObject.createFromByteArray(pdDocument, scaledImage, null);
        LOG.debug("size of scaled image is x: {0} y {1}", pdImage.getWidth(), pdImage.getHeight());
        int xForImage = (thePdfDimension.width - pdImage.getWidth()) / 2 ;
        int yForImage = (thePdfDimension.height - pdImage.getHeight()) / 2;
        LOG.debug("new x {0} new y {1}", xForImage, yForImage);
        try (PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(pdDocument, page, AppendMode.APPEND, true, true)) {
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(imgData.getTitle())) {
                yForImage = xForImage - 20;
                contentStream.drawImage(pdImage, xForImage, yForImage, pdImage.getWidth(), pdImage.getHeight());
                drawTitelAtTop(imgData, page, xForImage , yForImage + pdImage.getHeight() + 3, contentStream);
            } else {
                contentStream.drawImage(pdImage, xForImage, yForImage, pdImage.getWidth(), pdImage.getHeight());
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private static void drawTitelAtTop(ImageData imgData, PDPage page, int x, int y,  PDPageContentStream contentStream) throws IOException {
    PDFont font = PDType1Font.COURIER;
    int fontSize = FONT_SIZE_FOR_TITLE;

    float titleWidth = font.getStringWidth(imgData.getTitle()) / 1000 * fontSize;
    LOG.debug("title width is " + titleWidth);
    contentStream.setFont(font, fontSize);
    contentStream.beginText();
    float tx = ((x - titleWidth) / 2) + x;
    //float tx = x;
    //float ty = page.getMediaBox().getHeight() - marginTop + (marginTop / 4);
    float ty = y;
    LOG.debug("title offset x {0} y {1}", tx, ty);
    contentStream.newLineAtOffset(tx,
        ty);

    contentStream.showText(imgData.getTitle());
    contentStream.endText();

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but as you see my problem is java, so your javascript sample does not really help

Comment: Ok, good point and correct problem is the same for every language. Actually I try to follow your advice and transfer it to my code.

Comment: maybe you have a sketch where i can see what points x1, x2, x3 are ...  a image says more than 1000 words approach :-)